# Changing @Published value triggers Init in View

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am facing a problem initializing the view, it is reinitialized when the @Published property is set and I cannot figure out why.

The app structure is:
MyApp -> MainView -> fullscreenCover OrderView -> ListOfOrders -> fullscreenCover ProductView -> Bug Button. The view model is injected as @StateObject.

Here is a simplified version of the app I'm working on:

**View model**

```
class SystemService: ObservableObject {
  @Published private(set) var testValue: Bool = false
  @Published private(set) var products: [Product] = []
}
```

**The App declaration**

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
  @StateObject private var systemService = SystemService()

  @ViewBuilder
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      MainView(systemService: systemService)
    }
  }
}
```

**The main view**, which basically just shows a fullscreen modal view - OrderView

```
struct MainView: View {
  @StateObject var systemService: SystemService
  @State private var activeFullScreen: ActiveFullScreenEnum?

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button(action: {
        activeFullScreen = .order
      }, label: Text("Order Details"))
    }
    .fullScreenCover(item: $activeFullScreen, content: { item in
      switch item {
      case .order:
        OrderView(systemService: systemService)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The **Order View** contains a list of products.

```
 struct OrderView: View {
      @StateObject var systemService: SystemService
      @State private var activeFullScreen: OrderFullScreenEnum?
    
      init(systemService: SystemService) {
        _systemService = StateObject(wrappedValue: systemService)
    
        print("OrderScreen Initialized")
      }
    
      var body: some View {
        VStack {
          ScrollView {
            ForEach(systemService.products) { product in
              Button(action: {
                activeFullScreen = .product(product)
              }, label: Text("Prodcut Details"))
            }
          }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(item: $activeFullScreen, content: { item in
          switch item {
          case .product(let product):
            ProductView(systemService: systemService, product: product)
          }
        })
      }
    }
```

And finally the **Product View** where the bug is discovered.

The bug is - when pressing on the "Bug Button" the **ProductView** is dismisses, and OrderView's init calls and prints out "OrderScreen Initialized".

```
struct ProductView: View {
  @StateObject var systemService: SystemService

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button(action: {
        systemService.testValue.toggle()
      }, label: Text("Bug Button"))
    }
  }
}
```

Probably the issue in my fundamental misunderstanding of how Combine works, I will be grateful if somebody could help.

***** Additional info *****

If I add `.onAppear` to the Order View

```
 .onAppear {
      print("Order View Did Appear")
    }
```

The first call to `systemService.testValue.toggle()` from the Ordre View triggers `.onAppear`, but only once, only the first time. After that, the bug disappears and .fullScreenCover doesn't get dismissed anymore.

Comment: Calling `systemService.testValue.toggle()` from OrderView causes calling OrderView Init

Comment: So the main question - How changing the @Published value can cause the view to be reinitialized.
There are no .onReceive used anywhere.

Comment: Yes, it does. So what's the question? If you don't want it then move that boolean into separated view model.

Comment: The question is: 
How to use a `@Published` value from the `ViewModel` (which initializes in the root of the app) on the `.fullScreenCover View`, without the `.fullScreenCover` being dismissed every time the `@Published` value changes.

Comment: Ok, I see that reinitialization is not the problem itself, I've tried a few other views and the `.fullScreenCover` doesn't get dismissed there despite reinitializing the view.

Comment: More details: The bug happens and `.fullScreenCover` gets dismissed only on the first change of the @Published value. After that everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that the application may be trying to operate with four different instances of `SystemServices`.

`@StateObject` - *'A property wrapper type that instantiates an observable object.'*

`@ObservedObject` - *'A property wrapper type that subscribes to an observable object and invalidates a view whenever the observable object changes.'*

Instead of `@StateObject`, try giving `@ObservedObject` in the child views of App a go.

Good luck.